# Complete the pattern: 21VN, 32TX, 43QS,

Tags: pattern

The pattern comes from a [culture test](https://www.letelegramme.fr/culture-loisirs/miss-france-2024-reussirez-vous-le-test-de-culture-generale-des-candidates-quiz-6475616.php) online (in French). Some questions are actually about mathematics/logic. I absolutely do not understand this one, though, given the others questions it should be something extremely trivial

Question: Complete the pattern: 21VN, 32TX, 43QS, 54??

a. FE
b. DE
c. CE
d. GE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> c. CE

The solution is based on

> The first and last letters of the number.

Examples:

> **V**ignt et u**n**, **T**rente-deu**x**, **Q**uarante-troi**s**, **C**inqante-quatr**e**

Comment: Gah damn u lol oh well

Comment: waaaah and I was stuck in thinking like TX maybe it means TeXas? QS maybe Quebec-related?

Answer (score 1):

the pattern is based on the first and last letters of the French names of the numbers.

"21VN" corresponds to "vingt et un" (21), taking the first and last letters gives "VN."
"32TX" corresponds to "trente-deux" (32), taking the first and last letters gives "TX."
"43QS" corresponds to "quarante-trois" (43), taking the first and last letters gives "QS."
Applying the same pattern to "54" gives "cinquante-quatre," and taking the first and last letters gives "CE."

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> CE because 54 is Cinquante-quatrE in French - the letters are just the first and last letters of the number it’s paired with, in French.